# Index value -1 in Windows 10

Tags: powershell

I have a code snippet which works fine in Windows 7 but when executed in Windows 10 , output is not same as windows 7 and the index value is -1

I tried using IndexOf,LastIndexOf but still no progress

```
$a = (Get-Item c:\Temp\*.exe)

$b = $a.basename

$b

$search = 'Location: C:\Users\Desktop\'+$b+'.exe'

$c   = Get-Content -Path "c:\Temp\abc.txt"

$d = $c.Length

$d

$data   = Get-Content -Path "c:\Temp\abc.txt" |Out-String

$index  = $data.LastIndexOf($search) - $d  

$index  = $data.Substring($index) 

$index
```

I want to read the abc.txt file from the end till $search and the output must be till search. abc.txt file keeps on appending the contents hence I need the latest appending from the end .In windows 7 I am able to get but in windows 10 I receive index value of -1. Also to be mentioned I don't want to use tail.

Comment: An index value of `-1` indicates the last index of your array.

Comment: $index doesn't retrieve the content

Comment: Remove the `Out-String`. Where is `$g` being set? Single letter variable names make it so hard to read and understand your code - don't do it! `$a` could be a number of items because of the wildcard and therefore `$b` can be a bit arbitrary. In short - your code has lots of unknown, undocumented nuances and it is not clear what you are actually trying to achieve with it. Go back to basics and step through each line of your code and check that it's returning the expected value(s). Only then can we successfully debug the `$index` bit.

Comment: @gvee if Out-String is removed LastIndexOf doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure your have the `$d` variable right. Get content will return an array with each new line as new entry. The `$c.length` will simply return the number of lines in the file. So when you search up the index, it will find the last `$search` based on the actual character position (not number of lines), minus the number of lines in the file. Try changing `$d` to `$d = $data.length` ? I'm not sure that the `  - $d ` part is doing...

Comment: first of all you should't call 'get-content' twice. and you'll have to add '-raw' to your 'get-content' call if you want to retrieve the content as a single string instead of an array. thats why you don't get the expected result in the last 2 lines

Comment: @D.J -raw doesn't work in power shell 2.0 . Any alternative for -raw in power shell 2.0?

Comment: Alternatively you can use '$data = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\Temp\abc.txt")'

Comment: "\" is missing. `'Location: C:\Users\Desktop\'+$b+'.exe'`

Comment: Do we have any alternative to get the content as I am getting whole file ?